# Manually create Debug Token for BB10 fails

Tags: blackberry-10

i want to create a debug token for my dev device with the native SDK (momentics), but it fails without any error message (just: "error creating debug token).

Now i use the command line tools.

But:

**1. If i want to request a token:**

```
./blackberry-debugtokenrequest -storepass xxxxx -devicepin xxxxx -csjpin xxxxx client-RDK-00000.csj
```

i get:

> Error: Not yet registered to request debug tokens

**2. So i want to register (i'm already registered, but ok...):**

```
./blackberry-debugtokenrequest -register -storepass xxxxx -csjpin xxxxx client-PBDT-00000.csj
```

> Error: Error: Unable to register client '00000' because there are no
>   more registration attempts.  If you have already registered with this
>   server, then you should restore your signing keys from backup.  If you
>   don't have a backup of the keys, then you can order a new set of keys
>   at www.blackberry.com/go/codesignin

I have a backup, but what should i do with it?

I want to create a debug token, but the message says: not yet registered. 
So i want to register, and it says: already registered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, you only need the CSJ files to register with RIM, which you only need to do once. You can then safely delete them and your CSJ PIN.

If you have a backup file it means you have already registered which means you shouldn't be using the `-register` flag when attempting to create a debug token.

To restore your backup code signing key follow these instructions: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925

Once you have restored your code signing key you can create a debug token using the following command:

```
blackberry-debugtokenrequest -storepass developercertpass -devicepin 50F2D211 dt.bar
```

Comment: Still did not work for me. Comment by Lur worked, as you need to specify the -keystore argument too apparently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSJ files to register only one time. After that it cannot be used. Can you try  getting new set of CSJ Files from blackberry server? I think it might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Spanish [I recommended this post](http://androidesverdesfritos.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/convierte-una-aplicacion-android-a-blackberry-10/).
In the pdf, in page 9, you´ll found a bat to get a debug token of blackberry 10. This is the code:

```
set LOCAL_DATA_PATH="c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Research In Motion"
set CSK_PASSWORD=Pass of CA
set CERT_STORE_PASSWORD=Pass of web key 
set DEVICE_PIN=PIN of device

E:
cd "eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ajde_1.5.2.201302260701\blackberry.tools.SDK\bin"
blackberry-debugtokenrequest -cskpass %CSK_PASSWORD% -keystore %LOCAL_DATA_PATH%\author.p12 -storepass %CERT_STORE_PASSWORD% -devicepin %DEVICE_PIN% %LOCAL_DATA_PATH%\debugtoken.bar
pause
```